# for loop incorrectly plotting boxplot on same figure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have the code below where I’m trying to create three separate figures.  I’m trying to create a figure with a boxplot for each column from the list.  When I run this code it plots all three boxplots in the same figure on top of each other.  If I instead changed it to a histogram it works perfectly, creating a separate figure for each histogram plot.  Can someone please let me know how to fix this?  I’ve also included some sample data below.

Code:

```
for i in ['Fresh', 'Milk', 'Grocery']:
            data_df.boxplot(column=i)
```

Data:

```
print(data_df[:10])

   Channel  Region  Fresh   Milk  Grocery  Frozen  Detergents_Paper  \
0        2       3  12669   9656     7561     214              2674   
1        2       3   7057   9810     9568    1762              3293   
2        2       3   6353   8808     7684    2405              3516   
3        1       3  13265   1196     4221    6404               507   
4        2       3  22615   5410     7198    3915              1777   
5        2       3   9413   8259     5126     666              1795   
6        2       3  12126   3199     6975     480              3140   
7        2       3   7579   4956     9426    1669              3321   
8        1       3   5963   3648     6192     425              1716   
9        2       3   6006  11093    18881    1159              7425   

   Delicatessen  
0          1338  
1          1776  
2          7844  
3          1788  
4          5185  
5          1451  
6           545  
7          2566  
8           750  
9          2098
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df[['Fresh','Milk','Grocery']].plot.box(subplots=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Output:

[image]